# Looping over JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to look through this:

```
[
    {"leadID":"1","leadName":"Steve"},
    {"leadID":"2","leadName":"Bob"},
    {"leadID":"3","leadName":"Bill"},
    {"leadID":"4","leadName":"Jim"},
    {"leadID":"5","leadName":"James"},
    {"leadID":"6","leadName":"John"},
    {"leadID":"7","leadName":"Eric"},
    {"leadID":"8","leadName":"Tony"},
    {"leadID":"9","leadName":"Jason"},
    {"leadID":"10","leadName":"Paul"}

]
```

I am trying to do it using the $.each but I cannot get it right. Here was a test to the console:

```
$.each(JSON, function(k, v) {

    console.log(v[0]);

});
```

I am sure I am just not parsing the JSON right but I cannot figure it out. Ultimately I need to append the data to the options of a select input.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON first, if its not already parsed.

Some browser have this native:

```
jsonobject = JSON.parse(jsonstring)
```

If not, you can use jQuery

```
jsonobject = $.parseJSON(jsonstring)
```

Then, when it's an object, you can loop through it with $.each

```
$.each(jsonobject, function(x,v) {
   console.log(v.leadID);
   console.log(v.leadName);
});
```

Comment: This did it. You are right that I needed to parse the JSON first. It's working perfect now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool :) If this is a web page, you should use jQuery $.parseJSON. I don't think IE has the JSON library. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing it with jQuery. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use $.each,it would look like this:

```
$.each(myJSON, function(key, value){
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value['leadID']);
});
```

You don't need to do value[0]. Here is how I normally do this:

```
for (var tk in myJSON)
{
    console.log(myJSON[tk]);
    console.log(myJSON[tk]['leadID']);
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thanks for the help but I looks like my problem was because I was not parsing the JSON first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your example `k` will iterate over the indices of you array (`0..9`) and `v` will iterate over the objects..

so for example you could do (comments refer to the first iteration):

```
$.each(JSON, function(k, v) {

    console.log(k); // 0
    console.log(v); // {"leadID":"1","leadName":"Steve"}
    console.log(v['leadID']); // "1"
    console.log(v['leadName']); // "Steve"

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I looks like my problem was because I was not parsing the JSON first. Thanks